# Использование класса ограничений

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Задача заключается в проверке наличия у типа `T` функции определенного вида. Используем класс ограничений. За счет наследования вызывается конструктор. Не понимаю, как он вызывает статическую функцию, чтобы получилась (если все плохо) ошибка в строке с заданием адреса указателю на функцию. В к-ре же вроде просто присвоение указателю адеса этой функции.

```
template<typename T>
class Has_f
{
public:
    static void Constraints()
    {
        T* (T::*test)() const = &T::f;
        test;
    }
    Has_f() { void (*p)() = Constraints; }
};
```

Наш класс:

```
template <typename T>
class C : Has_f<T>
{
    // ...
};
```

Почему автор написал именно так? Можно же просто вызвать в конструкторе 
`{Constraints();}` или нет? Фрагмент взят из книги Г. Саттера.

Comment: Вызова в конструкторе и нету

Comment: А из какой книги? Думаю,он там все и объясняет.

Comment: Решение сложных задач на C++. Именно этот момент не объяснен. Что суть класс ограничений - я понял, как использовать тоже. Не вполне понимаю такой вызов конструктором стат функции. И вообще, почему бы ее тело не перенести в конструктор Has_f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызвать-то можно. Но зачем?

Все проверки чисто статические, не дающие никакого выполнимого кода, т.е. *никаких накладных расходов времени выполнения*.

**Update**
Есть у меня вариант в С++11 сделать попроще:

```
template<typename T, 
         typename = enable_if_t<is_same<decltype(&T::f), // Имя функции-члена
                                T* (T::*)()>::value>>    // Ее тип, что нам нужен
class C
    ...
```

Ну, или еще веселее:

```
static_assert(is_same<decltype(&T::f),T* (T::*)(int)>::value,"Error");
```

Гуру стандартов, что скажете?...

Comment: А как она (проверка) срабатывает? Вот вызвали мы конструктор Has_f, что дальше? К Constraints мы () не применяем.

Comment: Тут вообще-то `Constraints()` даже лишняя. Главное, что мы должны получить адрес `&T::f`. И если мы его получить не в состоянии (нет такой функции, несоответствие сигнатуры) - мы получим ошибку компиляции.

Comment: Так верно ли я понимаю, что смело можно поместить строку с получением этого адреса в к-р и убрать Constraints? Не вполне понимаю, зачем автор продвигал в книге подобную модель.

Comment: Как по мне - да, можно. Но, может, какие особые гуру стандартов найдут какой-то хитрый случай, когда такое неверно?...

Comment: Ну, я пока не гуру, буду делать по-простому.

Comment: Я тут еще один вариант набросал... Когда Саттер свою книгу писал, C++11 и в проекте не было :)

Comment: Предлагаю написать Саттеру письмо.hsutter@microsoft.com

Comment: Да, enable_if_t зайдет. Я дальше смотрю в его книге пример с проверкой, является ли D производным от B - там предлагаются решения Александреску и Страуструпа, которые в настоящее время могут быть с успехом заменены на is_base_of. Это синдром этих книг.

Comment: Ну так тогда же даже **С++03** - и того не было. Выкручивались, как могли...

Comment: @Abyx Что-то не очень соображу насчет перегруженных функций... Не дадите конкретный пример? И в вашем примере все равно, например, константная функция или нет - если VC++ не врет :)

Comment: @Abyx А, дошло... :)